# Server 2008R2 System Crashes when a non-local user logs in

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, bsod

I have a Server2008R2 box that is rebooting at "Applying Registry Settings" whenever an active-directory user logs in. If I remote in as myself it crashes, if I log in from the console as myself it crashes, but I can log in remotely and locally as the local admin account.

The stop error is:

```
The computer has rebooted from a bugcheck.  The bugcheck was: 0x000000d1
(0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000008, 0x0000000000000000).
```

A few seconds later in the logs show 27 different services failing to start on reboot.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you happen to attempt creating a custom Default User profile or modify the Default User profile in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These sorts of BSODs are very hard to troubleshoot. If the fault uploader to Microsoft isn't giving you anything useful, it gets worse.

In this case DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL is a pretty generic error. A lot of the Microsoft KB articles that touch on a stop-code of D1 also link to hotfixes, but figuring out which one might help you will require digging into the dump files.

Comment: Good call on the dump files, I'd never actually looked at them before, it was Broadcom BACS drivers.